# Vaadin multisession troubles

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a pretty strange problem: I have a web app that is based on Vaadin. When one user logs in and makes some actions, it goes all fine. When the second user logs in, the first user starts to use the session and the context from the second user... I have such kind of context loading:

```
 private Context getContextFromSession() {
    WebApplicationContext context = (WebApplicationContext) this.getContext();
    Context c = (Context) context.getHttpSession().getAttribute("context");
    if (c == null) {
        c = new Context();
        context.getHttpSession().setAttribute("context", c);
    }
    System.out.println("Current session: " + context.getHttpSession().toString() + " , context: " + c.toString());
    return c;
}
```

Does Vaadin actually support multisessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Vaadin supports multiple concurrent users.

However - as with most web applications/java application server combinations - you can only have one HTTP session open in a browser instance at a time. For example, you can't have two separate tabs in one browser instance, one for User A and one for User B.

It's a bit more complicated than that, but this is good place to start. Are you using the same browser instance, or is it two separate "client" machines/processes?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use different browsers. Also, I have figured out, that there must be one app instance for each session, but right now I am using singleton to get the instance of my Vaadin app. I am trying to move it to ThreadLocal now. I have found this link - http://devblog.mycorner.fi/55/threadlocal-pattern-with-vaadin/ - pretty useful. If you could give some more hints, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Avoid statics! ThreadLocal for Application access is definitely the way to go, if you need to have a static access method - but I have to say that although we have implemented the pattern, we use it very rarely.

Comment: The problem is, that the application is not "just mine" - it's a pretty big system =) And half of it is connected with the static getAppInstance... Right now I'm thinking how to change this thing - sure it has to be some sort of a wrap around the App class to store the ThreadLocal container... Any ideas?

Comment: Simply change the App#getAppInstance to forward to a static ThreadLocal. Probably easier if you post on the Vaadin forum with your existing code, and I (and others) will be able to help you better.